# Probability of all n koalas climbing up (1,2,...,m) trees other than trees i and j?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

Let i and j be distinct elements in (1,2,...,m). What is the probability of all n koalas climbing up (1,2,...,m) trees other than trees i and j?

My approach was to find the probability that no sloths climb up tree i and tree j.

P(no koalas up tree i) = ($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$

P(no koalas up tree j) = ($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$

P(no koalas climb up tree j and i) = ($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$ x ($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$

P(all n koalas climb up trees other than tree j and i) = 1 - (($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$ x ($\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}$)

Is my approach correct? Or is the last step not necessary?

Comment: The wording is ambiguous. Are all trees other than trees i and j to be climbed by at least one koala ? Or do you mean that trees $i$ and $j$ are not climbed by anyone, others may or may not be climbed ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm sorry, I omitted to mention that each koala will select a tree uniformly at random, so I believe it should be the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the koalas are selecting trees uniformly at random, I understand that the stipulation is that trees $i$ and $j$ can't be climbed, that is all. Other trees may or may not be climbed, i.e. trees $i$ and $j$ are "bad" trees.

P(a koala climbs a "bad" tree $=\frac{2}{m}$

P(a koala *doesn't* climb a "bad" tree $= 1- \frac{2}{m}$

P(no koala climbs a "bad" tree) $= (1-\frac{2}{m})^n$

**PS**

If, as you aver, all "good" trees are to be climbed and no "bad" tree is to be climbed, it becomes a complex [coupon collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem, where expectation rather than probability is computed.